# infimum of a sequence > 0, if the sequence converges proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $x \neq 0$. Prove that $inf({|x_n|: n \in \Bbb{N}}) >0$

$\mathbf{What}$ $\mathbf{I}$ $\mathbf{have}$ $\mathbf{so}$ $\mathbf{far}$

Suppose $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\in \Bbb{R}$ such that $x_n \neq 0$ $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Suppose that $x_n \neq 0$.

Suppose $x_n \rightarrow x +0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, this implies that $|x_n| \rightarrow |x|$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I'll now show that $\exists M \geq 0 \in \Bbb{R}$ s.t. $|x_n| > M$ for each $n$

Then $\exists N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N$  $|x_n-x| \leq \varepsilon$

Then $|x_n| - |x| \leq |x_n-x| \leq \varepsilon$ (by the triangle inequality)

or similarly $|x_n| \leq |x| + 1$ for $n \in N$

Let $M = min \{ |x_1|, |x_2|,...,|x_{N+1}|, |x|+1\} $, which implies $|x_n| \geq M$ for each n.

This roughly follows a proof in my book, but it seems off, even though I'm just starting to learn the subject material.

Comment: Show that if $inf({|x_n|: n \in \Bbb{N}}) = 0$ ,  there must be a subsequence converging to $0$ . Then the sequence cannot have a non-zero limit.

Comment: Could you give me a tip on how to start this, please?

Comment: $inf({|x_n|: n \in \Bbb{N}}) = 0$ means that as $n$ increases you will always find  $|x_n|$ arbitrarily closer to $0$ , so you have a subsequence converging to $0$.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that's similar to showing that a convergent sequence is bounded? It's the hint the teacher gave, and what I've tried to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you have to specify the choice of $\epsilon$. In the following I choose $\epsilon=|x|/2$.

Since $|x|/2>0$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
n>n_0\implies |x-x_n|\le\frac{|x|}{2}.
$$
Then, if $n> n_0$ we have
$$
|x_n|=|(x_n-x)+x|\ge|x|-|x-x_n|\ge\frac{|x|}{2}.
$$
Finally,
$$
|x_n|\ge\min\Bigl(|x_1|,\dots,|x_{n_0}|,\frac{|x|}{2}\Bigr)\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$